# Where to find the installer for SQL Server Native Client 11.0.5058?

Tags: sql-server, native-client

I am trying to track down some behaviour issues in our software which seem to dependent on the version of SQL Server Native Client in use. I have version `2011.110.2100.60` (aka `11.00.2100`) but our client has `2011.110.5058.00` (aka `11.00.5058`). I've been around the house on Microsoft websites, including MSDN, but I can't find a version more recent than the one I have.

Is there a reliable repository of the different versions of the installer (sqlncli.msi) for testing purposes, or a guide to which versions are bundled with other products?

Comment: Once I learned about Feature Packs, I found this useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jason_howell/archive/2010/10/25/list-of-sql-server-feature-packs.aspx. Shame it isn't kept up to date though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server version `11.00.5058` is SQL 2012 SP2, so you need to download [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43339)

There are several places where you can look up the exact version of a build number. Personally I use [sqlserverbuilds](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.be/) but there are others.

Once you find the name of the build you can use that to google and it may lead you to the correct version of the installer or feature pack you need.

If you click download on that page it takes you to a list of packages you can select that looks like this:

[image]